# Angular, exported enum not found during compilation

Tags: angular, typescript

Inside `models.ts` i have the following enum defined:

```
export enum REPORTTYPE {
  CUSTOMER, EMPLOYEE, PROJECT
}
```

Then i use it inside another class

```
console.log(REPORTTYPE.CUSTOMER);
```

The IDEA automatically imports the enum among other classes/interfaces from `model.ts`:

```
import {REPORTTYPE, ...more} from '../../../_models';
```

Everything seems to work fine, the IDEA is suggesting me the correct autocompletions so the imported file is working correctly. But then, when i compile it i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./classpath... 59:20-30
"export 'REPORTTYPE' was not found in '../../../_models'
```

Every other import from `models.ts` is compiling and working correctly. He just cant find `REPORTTYPE` for some reason although i declared it as an exported enum and the IDEA also recognizes it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the values in the enum? For example `CUSTOMER = 'CUSTOMER'`, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file and/or the enum. Check usage of `index.ts` and try direct import instead.

Comment: Shouldnt the file not be the problem cause everything declared there which is not an enum works correclty? For example, if i replace the enum with an `export const REPORTTYPE ...` everythings working correctly. The problem only occurs when using an enum. Renaming it didnt help too.

Comment: I see you use `import {REPORTTYPE, ...more} from '../../../_models';` so there should be an `index.ts` file. Is it true or it's just a simplified example? I experienced the same problem with enums. The source of the problem is the name conflict somewhere internally and definitely `index.ts` doesn't help. I had to get rid of them in my project and everything works fine now.